# Why is my code giving right output in codeBlocks but wrong output in HackerRank?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem of HackerRank. The problem wants me to find out if a string can be changed into a palindrome string or not with a certain number of changing characters of that string. That certain number will be given by input. I am giving the link of full description of the problem below.

In my code, I first checked if the string is already palindrome or not. Then I checked some cases under the first checking for the given number of changes to find out if that string can be changed into palindrome after changing the characters.

But I am getting different output for my code. Output that I found from code blocks is not the same as the output which I found in HackerRank.

[Here is the link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/richie-rich/problem) of the full problem statement

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(char str[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
}
void cpy(char qtr[],char str[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        qtr[i]=str[i];
    }
}
void rev(char str[],int n)
{
    int i;
    char qtr[100000];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        qtr[i]=str[n-1-i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        str[i]=qtr[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    char str[100],str2[100000],qtr[100000],c;
    int n,k,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(str);
    cpy(qtr,str,n);
    rev(str,n);
    cpy(str2,str,n);
    int same=0;
    if(strcmp(str2,qtr)==0)
    {
        same=1;
    }
    if(k==n)
    {
        c=qtr[i]+1;
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            if(qtr[i]==c)
            {
                c=c+1;
                i=-1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<k;i++){qtr[i]=c;}
        print(qtr,n);
        return 0;
    }
    if(same==1)
    {
        if(n%2!=0)
        {
            if(qtr[n/2]!='9'){qtr[n/2]='9';}
            else
            {qtr[n/2]='1';}
            k--;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(k<0){printf("-1");break;}
                if(k==0){printf(qtr,n);break;}
                if(qtr[i]=='9')
                {
                    qtr[i]='1';
                    qtr[n-1-i]='1';
                    k=k-2;
                }
                else
                {
                    qtr[i]='9';
                    qtr[n-1-i]='9';
                    k=k-2;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(k<0){printf("-1");break;}
                if(k==0){print(qtr,n);break;}
                if(qtr[i]=='9')
                {
                    qtr[i]='1';
                    qtr[n-1-i]='1';
                    k=k-2;
                }
                else
                {
                    qtr[i]='9';
                    qtr[n-1-i]='9';
                    k=k-2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            int arr[n];
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){arr[i]=0;}
            while(k>=0)
            {
                int g=0;
              for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
              {
                if(qtr[i]!=qtr[n-i-1])
                {
                    arr[i]=1;
                    arr[n-i-1]=1;
                    qtr[i]=qtr[n-i-1];
                    k--;
                    g=1;
                }
              }
              if(k==0){print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k%2!=0)
              {
                  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
                  {
                    if(arr[i]==1)
                    {
                      arr[i]=2;
                      qtr[i]=qtr[i]+1;
                      qtr[n-i-1]= qtr[i];
                      k--;g=1;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
              }
              if(k==0){print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k%2==0)
              {
                  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
                  {
                    if(arr[i]==0)
                    {
                      arr[i]=3;
                      qtr[i]=qtr[i]+1;
                      qtr[n-i-1]= qtr[i];
                      k=k-2;g=1;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
              }
              if(k==0){print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(g==1){printf("-1");return 0;}
            }
            printf("-1");return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int arr[n];
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){arr[i]=0;}
            while(k>=0)
            {
                int g=0;
              for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
              {
                if(qtr[i]!=qtr[n-i-1])
                {
                    arr[i]=1;
                    arr[n-i-1]=1;
                    qtr[i]=qtr[n-i-1];
                    k--;
                    g=1;
                }
              }
              if(k==1){qtr[n/2]=qtr[n/2]+1;k--;print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k==0){print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k%2!=0)
              {
                  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
                  {
                    if(arr[i]==1)
                    {
                      arr[i]=2;
                      qtr[i]=qtr[i]+1;
                      qtr[n-i-1]= qtr[i];
                      k--;g=1;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
              }
              if(k==1){qtr[n/2]=qtr[n/2]+1;k--;print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k==0){print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k%2==0)
              {
                  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
                  {
                    if(arr[i]==0)
                    {
                      arr[i]=3;
                      qtr[i]=qtr[i]+1;
                      qtr[n-i-1]= qtr[i];
                      k=k-2;g=1;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
              }
              if(k==1){qtr[n/2]=qtr[n/2]+1;k--;print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(k==0){print(qtr,n);return 0;}
              if(g==1){printf("-1");return 0;}
            }
            printf("-1");return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find previous questions about this HackerRank problem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=highest+value+palindrome

Comment: Can you provide specific examples where you get a different answer?

Comment: This code looks very familiar. Did you post it before?

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. It's a dangerous function because it has no bounds checking, and has been removed from the language.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the problem specification. You're not just supposed to change it to a palindrome, you have to change it to the highest possible palindrome. If the input is already a palindrome, you may still be able to increase it. E.g. if the input is `12321` and `k=1`, you can increase it to `12921`.

Comment: Other ways of input a string are not eligible for this problem in HackerRank , I think. I have tried different ways for input a string.

Comment: You're not allowed to use the standard function `fgets()`? BTW, `fflush(stdin);` is not standard C, `fflush()` can only be used to flush output, not input.

Comment: @Barmar... For the input 6 3 092282, I found the output from codeblocks is 382283 but  I found the output form the HackerRank is -1. why is this happening?

Comment: Please, suggest me a way to input 2 integer and a string.

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %s", &n, &k, str);`

Comment: Isn't `982289` the correct answer for that?

Comment: Yes. But isn't my answer also correct?

Comment: No. The requirement is to find the *highest* palindrome. 982289 is higher than 382283.

Comment: @Hassan As the linked page shows, `992299` is the correct answer. You're allowed to change 3 digits.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much for indicating the problem in my code.